# CSS limit border to table cell TD content

Tags: html, css

Hello all I'm just trying to have my border around my table cell right around the text...not stretched the length of the entire table.  Its the section with the border around it

[image]

CSS:

```
table.content_table {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.content_table > tbody > tr > td.results {
border: 2px solid;
background-color: #eeeecc;
font-size: 8pt;
font-weight: bold;
PADDING: 0px;

}
```

HTML:

```
    <table class="content_table">
    <br/><br/>
     <h1>Planned Vs Actual Productions Drilldown</h1>


            <tr>
            <td class="results">
         Number of results returned:  ${fn:length(beans)}
        </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give the text a simple span or any other block element like div p ... span with inline-block is also a block element which can have a border.

```
table.content_table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.border {
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: #eeeecc;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  PADDING: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Any Element inside a table needs to be in TD so that is is valid html... put another tr > td into your table like this

```
<table class="content_table">
<tr>
   <td>
     <h1>Planned Vs Actual Productions Drilldown</h1>
   </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="results">
        <span class="border">Number of results returned:  ${fn:length(beans)}</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the fact that you have table width as 100%. Without any of styling at the TD level, the TD is automatically going to take the most width it can.

The bigger question though, is why you are using a table at all.  This is a single column of data, no need for a table here, just use div's.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a WordPress theme. The "collapse" wasn't entirely working on the first column, because my theme's style.css "reset" had set the table width to 100%. At least for me, the "auto" width solved the problem.

```
<style>
  table#donations { border-collapse: collapse; width:auto; }
</style>

<table id="donations">
  <tr><td>Bitcoin BTC</td><td>1Prh5VnUJRQV3sARhEfQAMKv9UzGqgAMXg</td></tr>
</table>
```